# Cannot resolve symbol @color when used within module

Tags: android, material-design

Having an android clean/new project, 
when I create a new module (simply by doing: File-> New Module -> Android Library) and using within a layout xml the basic android material design colors e.g. **`android:background="@color/md_black_1000"`**
I get:

`Cannot resolve symbol @color/md_black_1000`

But obviously when using this syntax `@color/md_black_1000` within the default app module's layouts this works fine.

**Q:** How can I use android material design colors `@color/md_black_1000` syntax, within a new module? (I don't want to predefine it manually within my module's colors.xml file)

**NOTE:**

- **Solutions which did not work for me:** Clearing project, rebuild, nor reopenning Android Studio, nor deleting the build dir and building again, all did not work.
- Within the new module, using colors are allowed ONLY only with this syntax `android:color/somecolor` (but using this way I cannot see the material deisgn colors `md_*`).

**Image below describes my issue:**  (templib is my new module)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing this issue right now, try changing your compileSdk in build.gradle module level to 31 or something lower than what you have.